# In objective-c how do I use object_setIvar to set a primitive value?

Tags: objective-c, class, pointers, reflection, runtime

I have this:

```
Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [name UTF8String]);
CGFloat floatVal = [coder decodeFloatForKey:name];
```

I'd then like to do this:

```
object_setIvar(self, ivar, floatVal);
```

...but I can't just use floatVal like this - what is the syntax for using floatVal in this context?

Answer (score 5):

First, it is probably easier to use Key-Value Coding:

```
[self setValue:@(floatVal) forKey:name];
```

As for your question, I believe you have to first cast `object_setIvar` to an appropriate function type for setting `float` type, and then call it (not tested):

```
void (*f)(id, Ivar, CGFloat) = (void (*)(id, Ivar, CGFloat))object_setIvar;
f(self, ivar, floatVal);
```

Comment: I needed to cast `object_setIvar` like so `void (*f)(id, Ivar, BOOL) = (void (*)(__strong id, Ivar, BOOL))object_setIvar;` (this is for BOOL rather than CGFloat)